# SQL How to minimize Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day.

Table have rows:

```
name

стоматолог
стоматолога
стоматологом
врач стоматолог
врача стоматолога
врач-стоматолог
врача-стоматолога
врача стоматолога-терапевта
врача-стоматолога$
врача-стоматолога$1
врача-стоматолога-терапевта$
врача-стоматолога-терапевта$1
врачом-стоматологом
врачом стоматологом-терапевтом
врачом-стоматологом-терапевтом
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА БЕСПЛАТНАЯ
УСЛУГИ СТОМАТОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ ХИРУРГ-СТОМАТОЛОГ
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА-ХИРУРГА
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА-ХИРУРГА
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА ДЕТСКОГО БЕСПЛАТНАЯ ВСЕ ВИДЫ
```

I use next query:

```
    ...
WHERE name LIKE 'стоматолог'
    OR name LIKE 'стоматолог[$-()/ ]'
    OR name LIKE 'стоматолог[$-()/ ]%'
    OR name LIKE 'стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь]'
    OR name LIKE 'стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь][$-()/ ]%'
    OR name LIKE 'стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь][йюм$-()/ ]'
    OR name LIKE 'стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь][йюм$-()/ ]%'

    OR name LIKE '[$-()/ ]стоматолог'
    OR name LIKE '[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь]'
    OR name LIKE '[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь][йюм$-()/ ]'
    OR name LIKE '[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь][йюм$-()/ ]%'

    OR name LIKE '%[$-()/ ]стоматолог'
    OR name LIKE '%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь]'
    OR name LIKE '%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь][йюм$-()/ ]'
    OR name LIKE '%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь][йюм$-()/ ]%'

    OR name LIKE '%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[$-()/ ]%'
    OR name LIKE '%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь][$-()/ ]%'
    OR name LIKE '%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь][йюм$-()/ ][$-()/ ]%'
```

Tell me please how to minimize this query and really it?

P.S.: now we have 17 conditions in the query (in `where`). I would like to group all these conditions if possible.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Alexander now we have 17 conditions in the query (in `where`). I would like to group all these conditions if possible.

Comment: i think first you should comment all your where condition then uncomment them one by one.for example OR name LIKE 'стоматолог[$-()/ ]'
    OR name LIKE 'стоматолог[$-()/ ]%' will return same number of rows.
so 'стоматолог[$-()/ ]' is not require. and so on.

Comment: @Alexander i join to chat

Answer (score 2):

`name LIKE '%word%'` will fetch 'word', 'word second', 'second word' and 'one word three'.
So, remove redundancy in you `LIKE`s - that should reduce your `LIKE`s at least in half.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do that using loop through array of variables:

```
$column = 'p.name'
$variables = array('стоматолог[$-()/ ]','стоматолог[$-()/ ]',....);

$query= "WHERE {$column} LIKE '%стоматолог%' ";

foreach($variables as $variable)
{
     $query .= "OR {$column} LIKE '%{$variable}%' ";
}
```

Notice that we used the first variable in the first partt of the query before the loop